# SonarLint x Java GC, anular ou não objeto ao final da execução?

Tags: java, desempenho, gerenciamento-de-memória, sonarlint

Estou passando o SonarLint em uma aplicação um pouco antiga e corrigindo vários "problemas", porém me deparei com um trecho de código parecido com:

```
public void fazerAlgo(final String param) {
    MeuObjeto m = new MeuObjeto();
    m.setVar(param.toLowerCase()); 

    myBusiness.atualizarAlgumaCoisa(m);

    m = null; // <- Para liberar memória e ajudar o GC
}
```

E o SonarLint acusou o erro abaixo para a linha `m = null`:

```
Remove this useless assignment to local variable
(Remova essa atribuição inútil à variável local)
```

O ponto de vista do sonar é que esse objeto `"m"` não é usado depois da atribuição, então o `set` se torna inútil, isso faz sentido e em outros pontos de código onde isso acontecia eu removi a atribuição.

Porém, na época do Java 5, Java 6 (ou seja, hoje em muitas empresas), era comum os desenvolvedores mais avançados solicitarem coisas como "coloca `final` em tudo", "sempre inicie um *array* com um tamanho" e "anula objetos antes de sair do método", sendo essa última para economizar memória e fazer o *garbage collector* do Java limpar esse objeto mais rápido.

Qual dos dois está mais certo? Devo manter o `m = null`, até porque onde esse código está acontecendo os objetos são bem grandes, ou devo remover essa atribuição porque isso não influencia em nada na performance da aplicação e o SonarLint está sempre certo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Este tipo de utilitário não entende o contexto da aplicação. Se usar isso e não entender o que está fazendo, começará estragar a aplicação tanto quanto melhorará.

Neste caso ele está coberto de razão, quem fez esse `null` não entende como funciona o código. Não é necessário anular nada no código, a não ser em variável estática, que em algum momento não precisa mais ter um conteúdo armazenado. Mas se for o caso provavelmente o erro é ter feito essa variável ser estática. A afirmação da pergunta é um *non-sense*. Não importa o tamanho dele.

Se você considera esses desenvolvedores mais avançados, lamento ter tido influências ruins. De fato a imensa maioria dos programadores são ruins e não entendem o que estão fazendo, pior ainda quando essas pessoas influenciam outras. Por isso sempre procure fontes confiáveis, verificáveis por várias pessoas qualificadas.

A coleta ocorrerá sempre que for necessária em todos os objetos que não possuam referência para ele. O que está fazendo aí é isto:

```
public void fazerAlgo(final String param) {
    int x = 1;
    System.out.println(x);
    x = 0;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/Nulling.java).

Acha isso necessário? Tem o mesmo efeito.

O melhor dessa pergunta é eu poder dizer para desistir de boas práticas. A maioria das pessoas não as entendem e usam como se fossem receitas de bolo. Se não entender porque estão mandando fazer aquilo, em profundidade, não use! E digo mais, boa parte das tais das boas práticas simplesmente estão erradas porque foram criadas por quem não entende o que está fazendo. E mesmo nos casos onde elas fazem sentido, mas só em um contexto específico. O seu contexto pode ser outro. Tenho feito palestras mostrando como a falta de contexto tem causado atrocidades nas organizações.